# From Spark to Snowflake data types

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, types, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake.  I'm writing a spark df to snowflake, using this code.

```
var = dict(sfUrl="xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        sfUser=user,
        sfPassword=password,
        sfDatabase="xxxx",
        sfSchema="xxx",
        sfWarehouse="xxxx")

df.write.format("snowflake").mode("overwrite").options(**var).option("dbtable", "xxx").save()
```

The df has a few `StringType()` columns and when I check de data types in snowflake they have `VARCHAR(16777216)` type. It's crazy because their length must be 2. Is there any way to specify the varchar length when I write the data?
In this [reference](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#from-spark-sql-to-snowflake) it mentions:

> If length is specified, VARCHAR(N); otherwise, VARCHAR

But how can I specified length in the write command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this article from Snakeflow [Load Data in Spark with Overwrite mode without Changing Table Structure](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Load-Data-in-Spark-with-Overwrite-mode-without-Changing-table-Structure), you can set the 2 [options](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#setting-configuration-options-for-the-connector) `usestagingtable` and `truncate_table` respectively to `OFF` and `ON` when writing.

> [...] if you write the data into this table using
> Snowflake Spark Connector with OVERWRITE mode, then the table gets
> re-created with the default length of the datatypes. It's like
> VARCHAR(32) will become VARCHAR(16777216).
>
> [...] you can set the parameters TRUNCATE_TABLE=ON and USESTAGINGTABLE=OFF in the database connection string of your spark code and can run the spark data write job in "OVERWRITE" mode.

By default, the parameter USESTAGINGTABLE is set to ON because the connector writes the data frame into a temporary table, if the writing operation succeeds then the target table is being replaced by the new one.

So your code should be like this:

```
options = {
    "sfUrl": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "sfUser": user,
    "sfPassword": password,
    "sfDatabase": "xxxx",
    "sfSchema": "xxx",
    "sfWarehouse": "xxxx",
    "truncate_table": "ON",
    "usestagingtable": "OFF"
}

df.write.format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .options(**options) \
    .option("dbtable", "xxx") \
    .save()
```

Comment: If someone is also looking for the solution of problem with overwriting table structure but `usestagingtable` and `truncate_table` don't work keep in mind to use UPPERCASE values ON and OFF